# Post to a Facebook page that I manage using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am posting to a facebook page I manage using facebook API. Till yesterday I was able to post using facebook graph API. Suddenly I started seeing the permission issue for publish_pages permission. It is as if this specific permission has been revoked from the token (I verified using [token debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/)). When I try to generate a new user access token with relevant **publish_page** permissions, I do not see the permission for **publish_page** in the [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). 
The token I was using was generated using user access token with relevant permission to get a token for page.

From doc I see that we do need App review for publish_page permission. But so do we need it for manage_page permission. My token has manage_page permission and I can see option for this manage_page permission in [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) when I generate user access token.

I see option to get publish_page permission when I try to generate token for page. But when I try to select the option I get below error:
Invalid Scopes: publish_pages. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Do I need to get my app verified before I can post to page I manage?
What else can I try?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545282/how-to-overcome-the-newly-arised-200-error-while-posting-to-my-facebook-page-pr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug report about this: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2261820083829739/

I still get an error for one of my Apps that was working before, so I can confirm that it is still not fixed:

> Invalid Scopes: read_page_mailboxes, instagram_basic,
>   instagram_manage_insights

Edit: Just found another bug report about it: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/600976503711113/

Comment: I think this is the actual bug-report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/331730207440499/

Comment: there are many bug reports about permission errors right now, but i assume it will be fixed soon