# How to overcome the newly arised #200 error while posting to my Facebook page programatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've been using the PHP SDK to post to a Facebook page of mine for two years. Today I was greeted with this error:

> (#200) Requires either publish_to_groups permission and app being installed in the group, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission

I haven't changed anything, and as far as I remember, those permissions were not required when I need to post only to the page I own.

I use PHP SDK v.5.5.0. Here's my code:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'MY_APP_ID',
  'app_secret' => 'MY_APP_SECRET',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
  'default_access_token' => 'MY_NEVER_EXPIRING_TOKEN'
]);

$linkData = [
  'link' => 'http://example.com',
  'message' => 'Message',
  'description' => 'Description',
  'caption' => "Caption",
];

try {
  $response = $fb->post('/MY_PAGE_ID/feed', $linkData);
  $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
  echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];
  $status = 1;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getRawResponse() . 
  $status = -1;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage() . 
  $status = -1;
}
```

Any ideas what could have broken, without me changing anything in the code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You didn't break anything. Facebook changed stuff. Read their changelog

Comment: You must have been posting as a user then, which isn’t possible any more. You need to get a page access token.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any changes on their side which would affect my page in such a way. I was hoping that someone else maybe had the same experience and found the solution. If you could point me to their changelog, I'd be grateful, the last change that I found that maybe relevant was in August last year. It's long time ago, the problem would have occurred earlier if that were the cause.

Comment: @04FS I'm using access tokens, as shown in the code I shared, and am posting to the page feed. What else should I check?

Comment: Of course you are using access tokens, because without a token the API would not let you do _anything_. This is about the _type_ of token you are using. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Either that, or your did not ask for all necessary permissions, or your token doesn’t currently have them (due to the new permission expiry.) Debug your access token as a first step, to find out what you are dealing with.

Comment: It could also be this though - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54548479/10955263

Comment: @04FS thanks for your help! I'm using a Page type token, which is valid and never expires, generated 2 years ago. I suspect that the bug could be the cause of the issue, my problem is very similart to the one in the other SO question you referred to.

Comment: It seems to be this issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/331730207440499/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug, reported here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/331730207440499/
and quickly fixed by Facebook. Some permissions seem to have been revoked by mistake, and were later restored.